# Java: Is it possible to make line break x times inside for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, line-breaks

I tried to Google and search StackOverflow my question but I didn't found any answers to this.

I have made an array where both size and values are randomly generated. When the array values have been printed 20 times I would like to make a line break, but without printing the rest values with always new line.

Here is my code:

```
public static void catArr() {

    Random rändöm = new Random();
    int size = rändöm.nextInt(100);

    int[] arr = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        arr[i] = rändöm.nextInt(100);
    }

    Arrays.sort(arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        System.out.print(" " + arr[i]);
        if (i > 20)
            System.out.println(); //How to do this only once?
        else if (i > 40)
            System.out.println(); //Same here?
    }

}
```

And this is one of the generated outputs:

```
 3 8 10 25 30 31 34 38 46 50 55 59 62 66 67 68 68 68 72 76 76 81
 82
 83
 84
 86
 91
 92
 93
 94
 94
 97
```

I think that one way to solve this is using 2-D array, but I would like to know if there is another way.

Yay thanks to Patric, I got the wanted result:

```
0   2   3   7   7   9   11  14  14  16  18  19  24  25  26  28  28  30  30  31  
31  33  33  34  41  41  41  42  43  44  45  46  51  51  52  53  59  60  61  62  
62  62  63  65  65  67  67  68  69  70  74  74  76  78  82  83  84  84  87  88  
89  93  93  94  94  94  95
```

Comment: Does "if (i==20)" not do what you want?  It only prints once.  If you want it every 20 try "if (i%20==0)" which says "when i is exactly divisible by 20"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try using

```
if ( ( i % 20 ) == 0 ){
    System.out.println();
}
```

if i divided by 20 leaves no remainder then print a new line!

Comment: That's almost correct! I just don't understand why I get first value and then comes the line break. Like this: `code 4
 5 6 10 14 18 21 28 28 29 32 36 42 42 47 55 65 66 69 71 71
 72 77 91 95 98 99`

Comment: because if i = 0 then there is no remainder - try 

    if ( ( i % 20 == 0 ) && i > 0 ) {

Comment: oh now I solved it, I had to change int i = 1 to 0 in for loop. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Literally, this will do what you seem to want:

```
    if (i == 20)
        System.out.println();
    else if (i == 40)
        System.out.println();
```

But I have a feeling that you actually want to add a newline after the 20th, 40th, 60th and so on.

```
    if (i % 20 == 0) 
        System.out.println();
```

And if you want to output exactly one newline at the end, then you need something like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i > 1 && i % 20 == 1) {
            System.out.println();
        System.out.print(" " + arr[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
if (i % 20==0)
```

can solve your else if problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `(++i % 20) == 0` and remove `i++` from loop; *pre-increment* avoid first unwanted line break.

Answer (score 0):

You may use boolean for your Sys outs.

```
boolean myBoolean = true;
if(myBoolean){
    //print
    myBoolean = false; //set boolean to false.
}
```

On the other hand, in my preferences, I still stick with my integer flagging.

```
int isTrue = 1;
if(isTrue == 1){
    //print
    isTrue = 0;
}
```